# Rethinkdb get row position in orderBy of a particular user

Tags: node.js, rethinkdb, rethinkdb-javascript

I have the following rethinkdb data schema :

```
user_id -- generated by the application
point   -- given to the user on a successful completion of task
```

How can I select a single document AND its position amongst the other document in the collection, when sorted by score DESC. So if the collection data looks like this, when sorted by score:

```
user_id | score
---------------
10      |  100
01      |  90
...............
22      |  01
```

I was able to find a solution to a similar problem (with MYSQL as the database.)
Here is the link:
[MySQL get row position in ORDER BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614666/mysql-get-row-position-in-order-by)

Currently i am loading the dataset at Node.js level, but is this possible at query level computation ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the rank / row number for a row?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33330073/how-do-i-get-the-rank-row-number-for-a-row)

Comment: sorry, for the duplicate question, my query terms were wrong.